# Airflow - Set dag_run conf values before sending them through TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: airflow

I am facing an issue where i am trying to set dag_run.conf values inside the the code, before sending it through to another DAG via the TriggerDagRunOperator.

Example:

```py
    def _should_trigger(dag_run, **_):
        ***** Somehow set dag_run.conf values here******
        eg: dag_run.conf['Message'] = 'Hello World'
    
    
    should_trigger = PythonOperator(
        task_id="should_trigger",
        python_callable=_should_trigger,
        provide_context=True,
    )
    
    trigger_bar_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_bar_dag",
        trigger_dag_id="bar",
        conf={"payload": "{{ dag_run.conf }}"},
    )
```

Then in the Target DAG "bar", i want to be able to retrieve that value that was set in _should_trigger of 'Hello world'. Is this possible, as I have tried countless different ways and can't seem to figure this out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying DagRun.conf (which I suppose won't work as the changes are not persisted) I would try to generate the code and use XCom:

```py
def _should_trigger(**_):
    return {'Message': 'Hello World'}


should_trigger = PythonOperator(
    task_id="should_trigger",
    python_callable=_should_trigger,
    provide_context=True,
)

trigger_bar_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_bar_dag",
    trigger_dag_id="bar",
    conf={"payload": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('should_trigger') }}"},
)
```

or even simpler:

```py
conf="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('should_trigger') }}"
```

Mind that this dictionary has to be JSON serialisable to work with Airflow default XCom backend.

Comment: Hi Tomasz,

Thanks for your response. When i use this method, if i try to access the conf values inside the Target DAG, i get the below:
'params': {'payload': 'None'}


My Target DAG looks like below:

def run_this_func(**context):
    print(context)

@dag(dag_id="bar",
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=None
    )
def run_tasks():
    run_this = PythonOperator(task_id="run_this", 
        python_callable=run_this_func,
        provide_context=True)

Comment: What is your `_should_trigger` function? Also remember that you need `should_trigger  >> trigger_bar_dag` if you want to use XCom from `should_trigger`